# How to make a global object in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, global-variables

I want to make objects of my defined classes global but im getting error.
im doing something like this:

```
namespace HotelSystem
{
    public static class GlobalVariables
    {
        public static login_log cashier = new login_log();
        public static List<customer> customer = new List<customer>();
    }
}
```

and im getting this error:

```
Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'HotelSystem.Helpers.login_log' is less accessible than field 'HotelSystem.GlobalVariables.cashier'

Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HotelSystem.Helpers.customer>' is less accessible than field 'HotelSystem.GlobalVariables.customer'
```

Comment: Smelly static global variables.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried what the error was saying?

Add 'public' to login_log class and customer class

Comment: Making those two classes more accessible seems like a poor choice, when the other option is to make this "global" data less accessible (the more hidden, the better..)

Answer (score 3):

You can make your "globals" class internal (and use Properties, which is typically more idiomatic as it's safer for future proofing your API):

```
internal static class GlobalVariables
{
    private static readonly login_log cashier = new login_log();
    private static readonly List<customer> customer = new List<customer>();

    public static login_log Cashier { get { return cashier; } }
    public static IList<customer> Customer { get { return customer; } }
}
```

This will cause the accessibility to be the same as your other classes.

Note that making `login_log` and `customer` `public` would also "solve" the issue.  However, while I wouldn't recommend making static "global" data of this nature in general, if you're going to do it, keeping it internal within the assembly is likely a better idea than making it public.

Comment: +1 for `internal` - this is the **cleaner** way to do globals.  But still not a good idea to have globals *at all*.

Comment: @EvanL Couldn't agree more - making things public just to make global data work seems "dirty"

Comment: @LewsTherin `const` won't work, but they could be readonly - I'd prefer props, though

Comment: Oh right. Because of the `new` keyword. Yeah read only then with a private static constructor. And yeah for props (although might need to use a `private set`? ).

Comment: @LewsTherin That better?  :)

Comment: Brings me back to a little project I had to refactor after the previous dev quit... had a `SqlDataAdapter` in a Global scope... nasty.

Answer (score 2):

The error means that your `customer` and `login_log` types are less accessible than the fields which use them (i.e., they are not `public`).

A field's type must be at least as accessible as the field itself. Making `customer` and `login_log` `public` should solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

Check declarations of `login_log` and `customer` classes.  They're probably missing `public` keyword in front of them (making them internal by default and thus less accessible).